# Getting undefined on service called from html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm currently working on an Angular project and I am creating unit testing for a component using Karma + Jasmine, so I have HTML that has a `ngIf` calling the API Service as:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="apiService.utilsService.userBelongsTo('operations')"></div">
```

**TS**

```
export class CashFlowSalariesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
constructor(
public apiService: ApiService,
) {}
```

**SPECT.TS**

```js
describe('CashFlowSalariesComponent', () => {
      let fixture: ComponentFixture < CashFlowSalariesComponent > ;
      let mockCashFlowService;
      let data;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        data = [{
          id: 1006,
          role: "Developer",
          ...
        }]

        mockCashFlowService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['createTableData'])

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
          imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            BrowserModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            ToastrModule.forRoot({
              positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
            })
          ],
          declarations: [
            CashFlowSalariesComponent,
          ],
          providers: [{
              provide: ApiService,
              useValue: mockCashFlowService
            }, UserService, ProfileService, VettingStatusService, ApplicationRoleService,
            SeniorityLevelService, PlacementStatusService, EducationLevelService, UtilsService, ShirtSizeService,
            CountryService, CityService, PostalCodeService, StateService, ClientSectorService, JobService, ProfileActivityService, ProfileSalaryActivityService, ClientService, RequestTimeOffService, TimeOffTypeService, PulsecheckDetailService, PulsecheckMasterService,
            PulsecheckQuestionService, ExpenseService, DepartmentService, ExchangeRateService, SkillCategoriesService, ProfileRoleService,
            ToastrService
          ]

        })

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CashFlowSalariesComponent);
      }));

      it('should create', () => {
        expect(CashFlowSalariesComponent).toBeTruthy();
      });


      it('should set salaries data correctly', () => {

        mockCashFlowService.userBelongsTo = 'operations'
        mockCashFlowService.createTableData.and.returnValue( of (data))
        debugger;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(fixture.componentInstance.dataHeaders.length).toBe(10);
      })
```

As you see, I tried to set userBelongsTo as: `mockCashFlowService.userBelongsTo = 'operations'` but I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting
> 'userBelongsTo')

**ApiService**

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
 public utilsService: UtilsService;

constructor(private injector: Injector) {
this.utilsService = injector.get(UtilsService);
}
}
```

**Utils.Service:**

```
userBelongsTo(groupName: string) {
    return this.groups.split(',').reduce((c, g) => c || g.toUpperCase() == groupName.toUpperCase(), false);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined because you have not defined it. You need to add it to your mock and then have it return something.

```
mockCashFlowService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['createTableData', 'userBelongsTo']);
```

https://volaresoftware.com/en/technical-posts/mocking-calls-with-jasmine

Comment: I did that, also I added `'utilsService'` and trying to return value as:
`mockCashFlowService.apiService.utilsService.userBelongsTo.and.returnValue(of('operations'))` but now throwing error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utilsService')